# Sendmail on CentOS 6, with SRS

Tags: centos, sendmail, spf

I do some mail forwarding, but I'm also a big fan of SPF; I'm aware that I have a problem.

While my mail server was running Centos5, I was using pysrs as a milter, and it worked well - but it hasn't been updated for python 2.6 (much less the 2.7 that C7 will require) - so I reluctantly had to stop using SRS when I upgraded to C6 (which I needed to do for DNSSEC support, before anyone suggests going back to C5!).

Does anyone have SRS working with sendmail in a C6 environment, and how do you do it?  Or should I bite the very painful bullet and change MTAs to one that more directly supports SRS?

Comment: Do you use milters for anti-spam and anti-virus checks?  YES -> You may consider using MIMEDefang milter for "all in one" integration into **perl** script.

Comment: I do use milters - as it says in the question - so I'm definitely open to that, but a quick perusal through the MIMEdefang doco doesn't make me very confident that it does SRS.  If you havea a concrete pointer to SRS via MIMEdefang with sendmail, please write it up as a full answer!

Comment: It seems to be possible (see http://whatever.truls.org/mimedefang-filter.shtml ) but ask at mimedefang mailing list for current recommendations.